# Линукс запрет на удаление файлов в Samba

Tags: linux, файловая-система, archlinux, samba, разрешение

Задача состоит в поднятии файлового сервера Samba  на Arch linux и пользователь может видеть , редактировать только свои файлы а удалить вообще не должен иметь право . Удаление только рут . Я пробовал многое но в конечном итоге сработал только chmod 777 с другими разрешениями запрещает на создание или изменении файлов в диске . Но chmod 777 даёт разрешение на удаление и просмотр чужих папок . В виндовс есть ACL там можно изменить и прочесть но запрещено удалить . Как мне использовать эту же технологию ?

Comment: `man setfacl` - посмотрите в сторону ACL для linux, возможно это поможет решить вашу проблему

Comment: запретить удаление файлов в тех каталогах, в которых разрешено создание файла, невозможно — в *nix это принципиально одно и тоже право на запись в каталог... запретить удаление чужих файлов/каталогов можно с помощью sticky-бита, а запретить их просмотр — с помощью обычных прав... запретить отображение списка чужих файлов в каталоге на которой у пользователя есть право на чтение также невозможно — для этого я бы просто дал каждому пользователю отдельный каталог (и, возможно, отдельную шару)... возможно что-то придётся также подмазать настройкой acl и umask...

Comment: Хз как для пачки пользователей, но я делал неудаляемый файл для всех. Тебе нужно прогуглить (я к своему стыду не могу найти свою документацию, может даже и не написал) `xfs`, `chattr +i`.

Comment: Он запрещает вообще изменения файлов мне нужно чтоб пользователи создавали файлы записовали там а удалять мог только рут